# Deeplinking Deezer (radio and artist) in an Android application

Tags: android, deezer

I'm currently developing an Android application which is listing different types of multimedia suggestions for the user, one of the pages contain tracks, playlists, albums and radios from Deezer. I'd like to deep-link the app with the official Deezer app with an intent, so when the user selects a Deezer item in my app, it will open the Deezer app (if installed) with the corresponding content. Doing this with tracks, artists and playlists was successful, for example:

```
// for track - working
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("deezer://www.deezer.com/track/72435416")));

// for artist - working
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("deezer://www.deezer.com/artist/13639")));

// for playlist - working
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("deezer://www.deezer.com/playlist/163470191")));
```

So my question is, is deep-linking possible for radio and album endpoints? I tried it analogous to the examples above, but I can't seem to make it work. I was experimenting with the following intents:

```
// for radio - not working
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("deezer://www.deezer.com/radio/18")));

// for album - not working
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("deezer://www.deezer.com/album/7119917")));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the album link, it's working fine on my phone (using the latest Deezer application available on the Google Play Store).

For the radios, there are in fact two types of radio on Deezer : Thematic Radios (for example a radio on Dance Floor music, or classic music, ...), and Artist Radios (for example a radio on Daft Punk and similar artists). The links to use for these are the following :

```
thematicRadio = "deezer://www.deezer.com/radio/radio-42";
artistRadio = "deezer://www.deezer.com/radio/artist-42";
```

You can also link to a user's profile inside the Deezer app using the following url :

```
userProfile = "deezer://www.deezer.com/profile/42";
```

*Please note that, just like tracks deeplink, this will start playing the radio but wont display a specific page to the user (at the time of writing this answer, maybe this'll change in future version?)*